# Develop C# application in Windows to get Android battery status

Tags: android, adb

I was wondering how to start an application using VS and c# to create a program (*.exe) to get battery status from my Android device using ADB...any ideas, please?
I can´t install Android Emulator due to restrictions on my Windows 7 computer. Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is CLI which is called [ADB (Android Device Bridge).](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)
You can run `./adb shell dumpsys battery | grep level` to get battery level. I am not expert in C# but i think you can run commands programmatically.

But, Developer options must be enabled and device must be recognized by computer (I mean manufacturer drivers must be installed)

Good luck

Emre